# Is it legal to Start a Thread by Using Anonymous Class?

Tags: java, multithreading

Usually to start a thread we either extend the Thread class or implements Runnable interface and override run() method. But in the code below we are not doing any of above and in fact it is using anonymous class to create a thread. Is it really a good/legal/advisable way to start a thread in java?

```
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }

});

thread.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it really a good/legal/advisable way to start a thread in java?

**good?** -
whether its good depends on your requirements, if you need a thread to run some heavy function in a kind of fire and forget manner then it might be fine.

**legal?** - it is legal - this code compiles and runs just fine

**advisable?** - not really, this is probably opinion-based but I would advise to use [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) together with [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why I'd do this

1. Learning how to use anonymous threads
2. When I have a thread that has predictable behavior and I can guarantee completion within the thread.

I'd avoid this structure otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

It is a bad way to do it because you need to copy/paste the run method for each Thread.

It is the same reason of why using method/class instead of put all code in one file.

Answer (score -1):

buddy it totally depends on your requirement, there might be use cases where you need to access the private variables of the outer class hence you used inner anonymous class. And about the spawning new threads, say you are using it for a specific purpose say Network calls in that case you should use it properly where you design a thread pool and use a spawn a limited number of thread irrespective of number of network requests.